# Makefile can not find boost libraries installed by macports

Tags: c++, boost, linker, macports, dyld

I just installed boost 1.42.0 from macports using `sudo port install boost`.

Everything worked fine.  Now I have a project that I'm trying to build using a makefile.  Everything builds fine until it comes to the file that needs the boost library.

It says:
src/graph.h:20:42: error: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp: No such file or directory

That file is actually located in two places:
/opt/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp
and
/opt/local/var/macports/software/boost/1.42.0_0/opt/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp

In the file src/graph.h where it's looking for boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp, the include statement is here:
    `#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler the base directory where Boost is intalled.  You can do that with the compiler's `-I` command line option:

```
g++ -I/opt/local/include ...
```

Comment: Is there no way I can have all future projects that use boost automatically search for /boost in that path?  Do I have to do it every project?

Comment: It worked, but I'm still curious.  P.S. For anybody that wants to know how to build SLAM6D on a mac: Open makefile.options (after being renamed from makefile.options.macosx) and add this line at the bottom with the other CFLAGS

CFLAGS += -I/opt/local/include

Comment: @pinnacler - you could do `ln -s /opt/local/include/boost /usr/include`

Comment: BOOST_CFLAGS=-Ig++ -I/opt/local/include
worked like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add one of these paths to your include path.

You can include the version using this include:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
```

which defines:

```
#define BOOST_VERSION 104200
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_42"
```

Use this to verify if your compiler is using the version you want it to use.